# accíon contraria al deshabilitar links en una tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo la siguiente duda, estoy deshabilitando links en una tabla con este código:

```
$('#tabla_resumen tr a').removeAttr('onclick').click(function() { return false; });
```

Cómo hago para volver a "activar" los links, esto es, lo contrario a hice primeramente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para deshabilitar los links, lo haría de este modo

```
$('#tabla_resumen tr a').css( 'pointer-events', 'none' );
```

para habilitarlos, con esto:

```
$('#tabla_resumen tr a').css( 'pointer-events', 'auto' );
```

Ejemplo:

```js
$("#disable").click(function(){
    $('#tabla_resumen tr a').css( 'pointer-events', 'none' );
}); 

$("#able").click(function(){
    $('#tabla_resumen tr a').css( 'pointer-events', 'auto' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tabla_resumen">
  <tr>
   <td><a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/">link</a></td>
   <td><a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/">link</a></td>
   <td><a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/">link</a></td>
   <td><a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/">link</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="able">Activar</button>
<button id="disable">Desactivar</button>
```

Comment: funcionó muchas gracias a ti a stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Con el método `off` puedes quitar los controladores asociados a un evento (en este caso el `click`). Lo que no vas a poder hacer es recuperar el valor del atributo `onclik` a no ser que lo guardes antes de quitarlo:

```js
$(function(){

  function deshabilitar(){
    $('#tabla_resumen tr a').removeAttr('onclick').click(function() { return false; });
  }
  
  function habilitar(){
    $('#tabla_resumen tr a').off('click');
  }

  $('#habilitar').click(habilitar);
  $('#deshabilitar').click(deshabilitar);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla_resumen">
  <tr><td><a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="https://pildorasdotnet.blogspot.com">Píldoras .NET</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="https://pildorasjs.blogspot.com">Píldoras JS</a></td></tr>
</table>

<button id="habilitar">Habilitar</button>
<button id="deshabilitar">Deshabilitar</button>
```